# General approach for an Mac OSX drawing app (with obj-c)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl, quartz-graphics

I am planning to make a simple OSX drawing/painting app in objective-c/cocoa and thinking that the best approach is to (in a nutshell) use quartz in an NSView sub-class.

Question: should I look into using OPEN GL or will Quartz do the trick?  Will using OPEN GL mean a big performance advantage?

The app would be very basic and should (for example) be able to:

-paint in color
-paint with bitmap textures
-use gradient fills
-programmatic paint brushes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already "an app for that" - it's the [Sketch example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Sketch/Introduction/Intro.html) available from Apple's developer site.

Comment: Don't forget to mark answers as "accepted" if they work for you.

Comment: +1. When I first learned Cocoa way back, I dissected that sample for days. It was a deep well of interesting and useful design patterns.